# Facebook: Invalid redirect_uri

Tags: facebook, redirect

I tried to authenticate Facebook with following Uri

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=1689750417961516&redirect_uri=https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html&type=user_agent&display=popup
```

But it gives me an error

```
{
"error": {
  "message": "Invalid redirect_uri: \u0423\u043a\u0430\u0437\u0430\u043d\u043d\u044b\u0439 URL-\u0430\u0434\u0440\u0435\u0441 \u043d\u0435 \u0440\u0430\u0437\u0440\u0435\u0448\u0435\u043d \u043a\u043e\u043d\u0444\u0438\u0433\u0443\u0440\u0430\u0446\u0438\u0435\u0439 \u043f\u0440\u0438\u043b\u043e\u0436\u0435\u043d\u0438\u044f",
  "type": "OAuthException",
  "code": 191,
  "fbtrace_id": "DweCEFKDNfq"
}
```

}

I don't understand what is wrong with redirecting to Facebook page, not to some other site.

Answer (score 0):

I think you didn't fill in your some application informations.

- Check your Url Domain Name.
- Application settings for this URL must be complete in the Application Domains page of the application settings, complete with all your domains and subdomains.